# Defining an 'integer-multiplication' for semigroups

Tags: purescript

Given a semigroup, I want to define an 'integer-multiplication' formalizing the notion of 'doing something n times':

`intMul n s == s <> s <> ... <> s` with n occurences of `s` in the right side, for any `Int` `n` and `Semigroup` `s`.

This seems like a reasonably generic concept, so I suppose there is an algebraic/group theoretic structure for this already. If it exists, what is the name of this structure, and is it provided by one of the standard purescript libraries?

And if I need to write this myself: The implementation for this would be the same for each semigroup. Does that mean that a typeclass is not the right choice for representing this?

*edit*: To sensibly define 'intmultiplying' by zero, I think I need a monoid rather than a semigroup, so that `intMul 0 s == mempty`. And if I want to allow multiplying by negative Ints, I'd actually need inverse elements, i.e. a group. Which does not seem to have a typeclass in purescript, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, you might add this as a member of the `Semigroup` class with a default implementation. That way, you could implement a faster version if you had one available, like for the `Sum Int` semigroup, for example.

In PureScript, we don't have support for default implementations yet, but we could simulate it by providing the default implementation in am exported function. That way the user can choose to use the default implementation or not. We take this approach in several of the standard libraries.

```
class Semigroup s <= SMult s where
  smult :: Int -> s -> s

-- A better implementation might use an accumulator or a fold.
smultDefault :: forall s. (Partial, Semigroup s) => Int -> s -> s
smultDefault n s
  | n < 1 = Partial.crashWith "Cannot combine zero elements of an arbitrary Semigroup"
  | n == 1 = s
  | otherwise = s <> smultDefault (n - 1) s 

instance smultString :: SMult String where
  smult = smultDefault

instance smultInt :: SMult (Sum Int) where
  smult n (Sum m) = Sum (n * m)
```